# How do you maintain view states with Marionette JS?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, state, backbone-views

It seems that Marionette isn't designed to handle reusing views. What is an effective way to maintain view states (for all view types) since they're always being reconstructed?

My first thought was to capture state in the models, but I quickly parted with that idea as many views can reference the same model.

I did try reusing views in a couple of different fashions but wasn't confident what I was doing was correct. In each case, I felt like the Marionette methods I was overriding might break things (now and/or later).

I've found suggestions on how to accomplish this with pure Backbone, and also glanced at Giraffe which seems to handle state quite effectively, but I've yet to find a solution for Marionette.

Comment: please describe the issue you need to resolve

Comment: I'm not sure how to describe it any more clearly. Throughout my application(s) my views need their states maintained as the user navigates to and from the views. As the user is expanding, collapsing, tagging, hiding, and showing things, those elements should remain in those states until the page is refreshed.

Comment: So you can render view once and then interact with DOM of view rendered html..

Comment: I usually create a new `Backbone.Model` per `View` and it only contains rendering information and not the actual `Model` that was fetched with data. The `Controller` hooked to that `View` actually has the `Model` and listens to changes after which it triggers events on the `View` to say that something happened. I follow the following practice: only the `Controller knows about the `View`, backend communication and data model; only the `View` knows about the DOM and it's local `Model`. Hope I helped, cheers!

Comment: AlexandruB - That does help. I thought about doing something similar, to have Model objects that capture the state of the Views. I understand the Controller manages everything, but can you tell me how your Controllers associate the Views and State Models with each other?

Answer (score 2):

An easy unsaved state system for getting data to the template is:

```
View.MyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    serializeData: function() {
        return _.merge(this.model.toJSON(), this.options.state.toJSON());
    },
});

var view = new View.MyView({
    model: model,
    state: new Backbone.Model(),
});
```

With a little more advanced version you can use the model events too:

```
View.MyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;

        this.options.state.on('change', function(event, data) {
            if (_.isFunction(self[event])) {
                self[event](data);
            }
        });
    },
});
```

Then in your controller:

```
view.options.state.trigger('change', 'functionName', 'someData');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track your view states by using a ViewModel.

Sam talks a bit about this here: http://youtu.be/CTr-tTwRH3o

Comment: I tried this method, but in the example he's attaching the ViewModel directly to the View, which when closing the View would lose it's state. So more specifically then, I'm asking where/how to maintain state when Views are closed but may be recreated at some point.

Comment: In that case, I think you would save the view state to the model.

Comment: Indeed that's what I ended up doing for now, I think a better management system is in order eventually.